# Seaborn displot facetgrid do not share y axis

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to make a grid of seaborn displots, using the built-in row/col arguments within the plotting function.

However, I have a high variance in the values for some of my rows and cols, and the default is to share an `x`/`y` axis.

I need to figure out where to put `sharey = False` and `sharex = False`.
I can't pass them into `sns.displot` directly, and if I try and make a figure beforehand, it doesn't get incorporated into the `displot` object.

So in this example below, I need the second row to be scaled to have a maximum ~0.5, not 0.7 like the plot in (0,1), that's impacting the `y` axis scale of all the plots below.

Minimal reproducible example

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
plt.figure(figsize = (6, 6))
sns.displot(tips, x = "tip", multiple = "stack", kind = "kde", bw_adjust=.3, common_norm = False, col = "sex", row = "time")
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `facet_kws` (e.g. `facet_kws=dict(sharey=False)`)

Comment: Not working in seaborn 0.12.2.

Comment: @Soren It seems you need to add `common_bins=False` in addition to `facet_kws=dict(sharey=False)`. See [this issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2472). Then it works for me in 0.12.2.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Both `common_bins` and `sharey` should be `False`.